# Uploading youtube videos through a common account

Tags: video, youtube

Is it possible to have users of my site upload videos from their home computers onto MY youtube account? What does that involve and can someone point me to some relevant examples.

I DONT want to host the videos myself, even temporarily, unless completely unavoidable.These will be short videos though, maybe about a min or two long, not high def, so its not too unimaginable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Yes

Check out the Google/Youtube.com upload APIs, which include a mechanism for what you want to do.  The relevant sources of information:

- Youtube.com [API Overview Guide](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#data_api)
- Developer's Guide: [Data API Protocol – Uploading Videos](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_uploading_videos.html#Uploading_Videos)
- Developer's Guide: [Data API Protocol – Browser-based Uploading](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_browser_based_uploading.html#Browser_based_uploading)

Comment: 1. Is it not possioble for the web app to use my credentials, but get the data from the enduser's machine?

2. Do you know of any where where i can get the source code for something exactly liek this?

Comment: 1. I stand corrected regarding the upload to your account--youtube.com has developed a mechanism for doing this!  2. Nope, sorry.  But check out the links in my answer.  There is at least a starting point there.

Comment: @StuThompson Hey I  m also doing Same thing can u just help me out with ur suggestions ,I in trouble with these uploading videos to youtube by android application :) Please reply soon